# Multiple iterators and vectors in a region

Tags: list-manipulation, graphics3d, regions, iterators

I'm interested in vectors whose coordinates are multiple of icosahedron coordinates of the vertices times $n+\tau m$ with $n,m$ integers. Then I want to see if they fall inside an icosahedral region once I substitute the parameter $\tau$ with the parameter $\sigma$. I tried this but unfortunately doesn't work. Does anybody know what goes wrong? How would you rewrite it?

```
\[Tau] = (1 + Sqrt[5])/2; \[Sigma] = 1 - \[Tau];
icosahedronVertices = 
 N[PolyhedronData["Icosahedron", "VertexCoordinates"]]
Omega = ConvexHullMesh[icosahedronVertices];
test = RegionMember[Omega];
max = 100000;
n = 5;
p = 0;
randompts = Table[0, {k, 1, max}]; randompts2 = Table[0, {k, 1, max}];


 
 
 For[(k1 = -5; k2 = -5; k3 = -5; k4 = -5; k5 = -5; k6 = -5; j1 = -5; 
   j2 = -5; j3 = -5; j4 = -5;  j5 = -5; j6 = -5; k7 = -5; k8 = -5; 
   k9 = -5; k10 = -5; k11 = -5; k12 = -5; j7 = -5; j8 = -5; j9 = -5; 
   j10 = -5; j11 = -5; j12 = -5;),
  k1 < 5 && k2 < 5 && k3 < 5 && k4 < 5 &&  k5 < 5 && k6 < 5 && 
   j1 < 5 && j2 < 5 && j3 < 5 && j4 < 5 && j5 < 5 && j6 < 5
   && k7 < 5 && k8 < 5 && k9 < 5 && k10 < 5 && k11 < 5 && k12 < 5 && 
   j7 < 5 && j8 < 5 && j9 < 5 && j10 < 5 && j11 < 5 && j12 < 5,
  (k1++; k2++; k3++; k4++; k5++; k6++; j1++; j2++; j3++; j4++; j5++; 
   j6++; k7++; k8++; k9++; k10++; k11++; k12++; j7++; j8++; j9++; 
   j10++; j11++; j12++),
  {
   z1 = (k1 + \[Sigma]*j1)*
      icosahedronVertices[[1]] + (k2 + \[Sigma]*j2)*
      icosahedronVertices[[2]] + (k3 + \[Sigma]*j3)*
      icosahedronVertices[[3]] + (k4 + \[Sigma]*j4)*
      icosahedronVertices[[4]] + (k5 + \[Sigma]*j5)*
      icosahedronVertices[[5]] + (k6 + \[Sigma]*j6)*
      icosahedronVertices[[6]] + (k7 + \[Sigma]*j7)*
      icosahedronVertices[[7]] + (k8 + \[Sigma]*j8)*
      icosahedronVertices[[8]] + (k9 + \[Sigma]*j9)*
      icosahedronVertices[[9]] + (k10 + \[Sigma]*j10)*
      icosahedronVertices[[10]] + (k11 + \[Sigma]*j11)*
      icosahedronVertices[[11]] + (k12 + \[Sigma]*j12)*
      icosahedronVertices[[12]]
      
      If[ test[z1], {
        p++;
        randompts[[p]] = (k1 + \[Tau]*j1)*
           icosahedronVertices[[1]] + (k2 + \[Tau]*j2)*
           icosahedronVertices[[2]] + (k3 + \[Tau]*j3)*
           icosahedronVertices[[3]] + (k4 + \[Tau]*j4)*
           icosahedronVertices[[4]] + (k5 + \[Tau]*j5)*
           icosahedronVertices[[5]] + (k6 + \[Tau]*j6)*
           icosahedronVertices[[6]] + (k7 + \[Tau]*j7)*
           icosahedronVertices[[7]] + (k8 + \[Tau]*j8)*
           icosahedronVertices[[8]] + (k9 + \[Tau]*j9)*
           icosahedronVertices[[9]] + (k10 + \[Tau]*j10)*
           icosahedronVertices[[10]] + (k11 + \[Tau]*j11)*
           icosahedronVertices[[11]] + (k12 + \[Tau]*j12)*
           icosahedronVertices[[12]];
        randompts2[[p]] = z1;}](* 
   If the point is in Omega then save it*)
   }]
Graphics3D[{Blue , Point@#} & /@randompts]
```

Comment: "col" is not defined.

Comment: I edited but doesn't work either...

Comment: "randompts" is a list of zeros. However, coordinates of a point should be tuples of numbers.

Comment: So how should I define them? I thought that settin randompts[[p]]=... I was setting the coordinates...

Comment: You are defining a function in which you define `randompts`, but you are not calling that function (`DirichletCoordinate`).

Comment: To create 20 random points you may e.g. write `randompt= RandomReal[{-1,1},{20,2}]`